# Codeblocks adding files to current project doesn't work

Tags: codeblocks

What I mean by this is that usually in codeblocks when you create a new file while you have a project open asks you to add it to the project, and when you do it'll be tied to it so when you open the project file it will have the files with it, but this doesn't work for some reason, also right click in management doesn't work, just the whole management panel seems to be broken.

**TL;DR: Codeblocks doesn't add newly created files to current open project file.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get all sorts of errors and crashes in CodeBlocks... I'd create the file you want, then manually add it to the project folder (outside of CodeBlocks with file explorer/Finder/terminal) you want it in and refresh...

Comment: Real quick how do I refresh? Kinda new to codeblocks

Comment: If it doesn't automatically refresh, right click the containing folder in the file tree and select "Refresh".

Comment: The thing is, I can't right click in the environment tab (as I said in my post), is there a way to fix this, or at least another way to refresh?

Comment: If you're on a Windows machine you can try the F5 key. Closing the project, and closing CodeBlocks, then reopening CodeBlocks and your project should also refresh. If you're on a Mac, I'll check it when I get home later (if I can get CodeBlocks to run). If you're on Linux, I might not be able to help